# How to create new notebook in evernote from android application?

Tags: android, evernote

I have referred [this](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android/blob/master/README.md), I have integrated successfully, now I want to create Notebook from app for that I tried below code but I am getting every time exception.

```
 Note myNote = new Note();
 myNote.setTitle("My Test Notebook");                   
 createNoteInAppLinkedNotebook(myNote, new OnClientCallback<Note>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(Note data) {
 }
 @Override
 public void onException(Exception exception) {
 Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
  }
 }); 

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void createNoteInAppLinkedNotebook(final Note note,final OnClientCallback<Note> createNoteCallback) {
    showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
    invokeOnAppLinkedNotebook(new OnClientCallback<Pair<AsyncLinkedNoteStoreClient, LinkedNotebook>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(
                final Pair<AsyncLinkedNoteStoreClient, LinkedNotebook> pair) {
            pair.first.createNoteAsync(note, pair.second,
                    createNoteCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception exception) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error creating linked notestore", exception);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.error_creating_notestore, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting **Error creating linked notestore** exception everytime.

Is there any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my own question's solution:

```
    Notebook nb = new Notebook();
    nb.setName("My Test Notebook");

    try {
        AsyncNoteStoreClient asyncNoteStoreClient = mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient();
        asyncNoteStoreClient.createNotebook(nb, new OnClientCallback<Notebook>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Notebook data) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSucceess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onException");

            }
        });
    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```